# 502 Bad Gateway при запросе к несуществующему домену с помощью curl

Tags: php, nginx, curl, php-fpm

Есть обычный запрос curl для получения заголовка

```
$ch = curl_init('http://russs.stackoverflow.com/');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $http_code >= 200 && $http_code < 300 ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

Дело в том, что когда curl натыкается на домен, которого не существует, nginx (вызывающий *php-fpm*) прерывает немедленно запрос с ошибкой

> 502 Bad Gateway

В логах пишет это:

> upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client...

С apache раньше такого не было. К сожалению перехватить ошибку на стороне php у меня не выходит. Нужно копаться в nginx.

Как это излечить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32837816/4827341

Comment: @alexander barakin не работает.

Comment: попробуйте в *try-catch* обернуть. p.s. главное — к nginx это, по-моему, не имеет никакого отношения. «вылет» происходит либо в php-обёртке вокруг *libcurl*, либо, вероятнее, в самой *libcurl*.

Comment: @alexander barakin и try-catch не берет...

Comment: значит, наиболее разумным выходом, с моей точки зрения, остаётся верификация доменного имени **до** обращения к *libcurl*. менее разумным выходом, вероятно, будет «ковыряние» в коде *libcurl* с целью перехвата исключения. вариант того же выхода — смена версии *libcurl* (на ту, про которую вы написали: *раньше такого не было*).

Comment: Чего это nginx-то прерывает запрос, если по вашим собственным словам он в логах пишет, что соединение было закрыто вышестоящим сервером? "upstream prematurely closed connection"

Comment: @МАН69К адреса http://russs.stackoverflow.com/ не существует, следовательно и сервера не также нет. Мой сервер закрывает соединение, а не тот куда я обращаюсь. О чем вы?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin когда apache стоял без nginx+php-fpm такой ошибки не было. Библиотеки были последней версии.

Comment: @user2569746, я о том, что nginx - не последний пункт обработки вашего запроса. Он передаёт запрос либо на Apache, либо на php-fpm, либо ещё куда-нибудь. В вашем случае - на php-fpm, судя по вашим комментариям. Вот именно там и происходит закрытие. Nginx же лишь констатирует факт, но не закрывает его сам. Поэтому - вам следует сосредоточиться на том, что происходит в PHP коде, в nginx копать нечего.

Comment: @user2569746, возможно, код *libcurl* вызывался тот же самый. но вот вызывал его **совсем другой** код (собранный в виде «апачевского» модуля *php*-интерпретатор). значит, методом исключения, я вижу только один выход: верификация доменного имени **до** обращения к *libcurl*. // а МАН69К пишет вам вполне очевидные вещи: ведь для *nginx-а* «апстримом» (в данном случае) является именно *php-fpm*, интерпретирующий ваш *php-код*. код «вылетает» — соединение между *nginx* и *php-fpm* разрывается.

Comment: Все нормально там с интерпретаторами и тд. Проблему решил. Благодарю всех за участие.

Comment: @Max_Payne ты ответ-то напиши, как конкретно решил

Comment: @strangeqargo https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=816669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> upstream prematurely closed connection

по результатам дискуссии выяснилось, что используется «upstream» в виде *php-fpm*, который в результате взаимодействия с *libcurl* «вылетает» при обращении к несуществующему доменному имени, что и приводит к выдаче программой *nginx* этого сообщения.

предлагаемый мною выход: проверять существование доменного имени **до** обращения к *libcurl*. например, с помощью функции [*checkdnsrr*](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.checkdnsrr.php):

```
$ php -r 'if (checkdnsrr("ru.stackoverflow.com", $type="A")) { echo "da\n";} else {echo "net\n";}'
da
$ php -r 'if (checkdnsrr("rus.stackoverflow.com", $type="A")) { echo "da\n";} else {echo "net\n";}'
net
```

---

а извлекать доменное имя из *url* можно, например, с помощью функции [*parse_url*](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php):

```
$ php -r 'echo parse_url("http://rus.stackoverflow.com/blabla", $component=PHP_URL_HOST); echo "\n";'
rus.stackoverflow.com
```

---

**по поводу неработоспособности *ipv6***:

можно ограничить *libcurl* работой только с *ipv4* (см. [документацию](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Comment: Ваш скрипт с функцией checkdnsrr мне всегда выдает 'da' независимо верный ли адрес или нет. Ограничение libcurl работает. Кому пригодится пускай использует. У меня кучи скриптов с curl подключениями, поэтому я пока обойдусь методом выключения ipv6 в resolv.conf, до тех пока не пофиксят этот баг для debian 8.

Comment: @Max_Payne, вполне допускаю, что я написал пример микро-скрипта некорректно (хотя на трёх разных машинах он у меня работает именно так, как надо). надеюсь, что всё-таки сама функция *checkdnsrr* достаточно работоспособна.

Answer (score 1):

Решение от автора вопроса из комментариев:

[bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=816669](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=816669)

Answer (score 0):

1. использовать `file_get_contents()`
2. увеличить время ожидания в nginx

Comment: Не работает. Время ожидания в nginx стоит больше чем достаточно. Если сайта не существует, зачем увеличивать время ожидания? Nginx через секунду прерывает запрос и выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Возникает когда IPv6 адрес получен, IPv6 DNS серверы прописаны, но нет IPv6 маршрутов.

В `/etc/resolv.conf` закомментировать все IPv6 DNS сервера.

Comment: я упомянул и про ipvx в своём ответе.